# 1C Bitrix: property custom type

Tags: time, types, properties, bitrix

We have "Date/Time" property type in Bitrix. But there is no "Time" type.

I tried to google it but I get a bunch of code without comments and there is no explanations where I need to put it.

I also tried to search in Bitrix Market place but without success too.

Please help me to understand how to implement "Time" type for infoblock properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just time - fastest workaround is to save time as usual string property.

Answer (score 1):

In Bitrix best solution for this is not making custom property types and use types, that you alredy have.

If you need store "timestamp" (*1472356615 - like this*), make property with type "integer" and CODE like "TIME_OF_EVENT" (letters in code field must be capitalised).

If you need save string like this "*23:45:59*", better use "string" type.

If you want automated data validation, you can use Bitrix Event Handlers to check specific fields before updating elements in Infoblock.